# Real-time speech recognition with multiple languages using python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, real-time

I'm still a newbie in speech recognition.

Is there any way to make my chatbot can understand multiple languages without telling the user to specify the language he is going to talk in.

The chatbot is coded in python.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I believe there are multilingual speech recognition models but you might want to use multiple models. The first is to detect the language and depending on what it detects use the appropriate speech recognition model second.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer! the problem is detecting the language needs a string as input, so the audio must first be translated into text and this is done as far as I know using a recognition model of a specified language. Am I wrong?

Comment: Speech language detection (from audio) is an evolving field, but there are some services available to use. These two articles may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-automatic-language-detection?pivots=programming-language-python and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-ai/automatically-detect-audio-language-with-the-speech-language/ba-p/1694363. I'm not affiliated with Microsoft in any way... these are just two of the top search results that came back.